# Rollback under condition in MariaDB

Tags: sql, transactions, mariadb

I have a transaction which reduces the variable with amount of money in loop, if the variable with money is below 0, the money amount should return to the value before transaction. How can I appropriately use rollback in MariaDB in this case?

---edit

I have something like that, and it doesn't work, check out the lines in `if(budget<0)` because if the money is below 0 and some, but not all of them, iterations were made and saved to the temp table, the table shows them

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE temppesel text;
    DECLARE tempsalary int;
    DECLARE budget int DEFAULT cash;
    DECLARE done bool DEFAULT false;
    DECLARE occ CURSOR FOR (SELECT pesel, pensja FROM pracownicy where zawod=occupation);
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = true;

    START TRANSACTION;
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp;
        CREATE TABLE temp ( Result text );
        OPEN occ;
            occ : LOOP
                FETCH occ INTO temppesel, tempsalary;
                SET budget = budget - tempsalary;

                IF(done) THEN
                    LEAVE occ;
                END IF;

                IF(budget<0) THEN
                    ROLLBACK;
                    LEAVE occ;                      
                END IF;

                INSERT INTO temp VALUES (concat('********',substr(temppesel,9,3), ', wyplacono')); 
            END LOOP;
        CLOSE occ;

        SELECT * FROM temp;
        DROP TABLE temp;
    COMMIT;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the `CREATE TABLE` statements are causing the transaction to be committed. [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html) is a list of commands that cause an implicit `COMMIT`.

As the aforementioned link describes, you can either move the `START TRANSACTION` statement after the `DROP` and `CREATE` commands or use the `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` syntax to create a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp ( Result text );
```

Comment: I just remove DROP and add TEMPORARY to the table temp and it works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN;
do some SQL
Loop:
    do some SQL
    if something is wrong, ROLLBACK and exit the loop and transaction
    do some SQL
if something, go back to Loop
do some SQL
COMMIT;
```

That is, let `ROLLBACK` undo *everything* since the `BEGIN`.

**More**

Now that the SP is visible...

- What engine is `temp`?  If it MyISAM, then it is not rolled back.  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'default_storage_engine';`.
- Please don't use `occ` for 2 different things, it confuses the reader.
- Do you want the output to be part of the rows of `pracownicy` when the budget is blown?  Or do you want *no* rows?
- If you have multiple connections doing the same thing, there is a serious problem -- `temp` is visible to all connections, and they could step on each other.  Change to `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp ...`
- However, with the pre-test (below), you can completely avoid the use of `temp`.  First test for its need, then (if needed) simply do a single `SELECT` for all the rows.
- If you want nothing, then a simple test something like this would pre-test whether it will overflow, therey obviating the need for testing in the loop:

..

```
IF ( SELECT  SUM(pensja)
    FROM  pracownicy
    where  zawod=occupation ) > budget )
```

Comment: I posted my code after improvements, I think it should be done in the other way than in the code, can you tell me what should I do more?

Comment: @jakub1998 - I added "more" to my Answer.