# How to rollback a transaction after If statement in MariaDB

Tags: sql, transactions, mariadb

Ok, let's say I want to transfer funds from one user to another. 
My plan is to do it in these steps:

> 1- start a transaction
>
> 2- check if the user has sufficient funds. If it has, go to the next
>   step, if not, Rollback!
>
> 3- if it has enough funds, withdraw funds, and transfer it to the
>   target's account.

My problem is that I don't know how to implement the second step
I need a piece of code to understand what syntax I should use for this.

Comment: adding table structures would help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rollback under condition in MariaDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47272015/rollback-under-condition-in-mariadb)

Comment: What client language are you using?  The `IF` statement can be used in MariaDB only inside a Stored routine.